# Make Func<> for a generic type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this architecture.

```
public void Init()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(Transform).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos)
        {
            // Save getter
            MethodInfo method = info.GetGetMethod();
            System.Type returnType = method.ReturnType;


            System.Func<Transform, Vector3> fact = GetFactory<Transform, Vector3>(method);

            Vector3 v = fact(this.Value);
            Debug.Log("Test123 " + v);

            //_getters.Add(info.Name, newMethod);
        }
    }

    static System.Func<T, T1> GetFactory<T, T1>(MethodInfo info)
    {
        return (System.Func<T, T1>)GetFactory(typeof(T), typeof(T1), info);
    }

    static object GetFactory(System.Type type, System.Type type1, MethodInfo info)
    {
        System.Type funcType = typeof(System.Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, type1);
        return System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, info);
    }
```

It even works if `method.ReturnType` is `Vector3`.
But I want the `func<Transform, Vector3>` to be `func<Transform, ReturnType>`.
I have no idea doing this.

Does someone of you know how I can do this?

And I also have no idea how to save the result in a dictionary.
Which type can the dictionary be of?

```
 public Dictionary<string, System.Func<object, object>> _getters = new Dictionary<string, System.Func<object, object>>();
```

[image: Illustration]

Edit: No ideas?

Comment: Is there a relationship between `Vector3` and `ReturnType`?

Comment: Not directly. Sometimes the `returnType` is a `Vector3` inside the loop.
But it also can bei a string or a bool.

Comment: No idea? :/ I really need help on this.

Comment: What are you trying to do, maybe we can help with the original problem? :)

Comment: @Caramiriel I want to list all properties of a type and save their getter to access data over name.
I don't want to use reflection only, because of performance.
MethodInfo method = info.GetGetMethod();
                var newType = typeof(Get<>).MakeGenericType(method.ReturnType);
                statDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(newType, method);
                var obj = statDelegate.DynamicInvoke(this.Value);
This was my first try. It works perfectly, but not in Unity game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get from the comment, is that you want to access getters through a string key? If that is the case, you might want to use the code sample below.

The entity you want to access:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Foo { get { return 42; } }
    public string Bar { get { return "Magic"; } }
}
```

The class that allows you to access the properties by name:

```
class PropertyCaller<T>
{
    // Static for each type T
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Func<T, object>> _propertyLookup;

    static PropertyCaller()
    {
        _propertyLookup = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>();

        Type objectType = typeof (T);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties())
        {
            const BindingFlags num = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            MethodInfo getMethod = prop.GetGetMethod(true);
            _propertyLookup.Add(prop.Name, item => getMethod.Invoke(item, num, null, null, null));
        }
    }

    public static object Call(T obj, string propertyName)
    {
        Func<T, object> f;

        if (!_propertyLookup.TryGetValue(propertyName, out f))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        return f(obj);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Entity e = new Entity();
var a = PropertyCaller<Entity>.Call(e, "Foo"); // 42
var b = PropertyCaller<Entity>.Call(e, "Bar"); // Magic
```

Comment: This works perfetly!
I added a direct typecast to the method.
T Call<T>(string propertyName)

Comment: Just wondering, but... Since you already know the type at compiletime, why don't you call the get-method directly?